# Zinnia has no content field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I have setup Django CMS with Zinnia for the first time. However in the admin area there is no place to enter actual content! See image...

[image]

Everything else works. What I'm I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What do you have inside `Publications` & `Templates` ?

Comment: @Liarez updated OP showing what is in publications and templates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using this plugin `https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/cmsplugin-zinnia` which reset admin page [here](https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/cmsplugin-zinnia/blob/develop/cmsplugin_zinnia/admin.py#L34) if you're set `cmsplugin_zinnia.placeholder.EntryPlaceholder` as `ENTRY_BASE_MODEL`.

As you see this code cuts the original fieldset and remove `content` field:

```
fieldsets = (
    (_('Content'), {'fields': (('title', 'status'), 'image')}),) + \
    EntryAdmin.fieldsets[1:]
```

So I see only one solution is to set another model as `ENTRY_BASE_MODEL` which you need to create:

```
from zinnia.models_bases.entry import AbstractEntry

class Entry(AbstractEntry):
    pass
```

And finally set correct `settings.py`

```
ENTRY_BASE_MODEL = 'path_to_module.Entry'
```

I hope this will help you :)

**Note**

I digged out why the hell they reset `fieldset` the original admin. This is explained [here](https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/cmsplugin-zinnia/issues/39#issuecomment-62867529).